# Variable subscript in AxesLabel

Tags: plotting, labeling, subscript

I am calling $y_{n}=x^{n}$ and I want to plot $ln(y_{n})$ for a number of different integer values of $n$ (I know this is very simple- it's actually a much simpler version of what I'm actually trying to do). If I execute

```
Table[Plot[Log[x^n], {x, 0, 1}, 
  AxesLabel -> {"x", "ln(" Subscript[y, n] ")"}], {n, 1, 3}]
```

the final part of the $y$ axis label moves to the front. Is there any way to avoid this whilst also properly displaying the subscript. Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: That's because you are effectively *multiplying* the strings by the Subscript expression, since they are separated by a space. Use `Row[{"ln(", Subscript[y, n], ")"}]` instead instead of your `"ln(" Subscript[y, n] ")"`.

Comment: Alternatively, you can use `StringForm`, e.g., `Plot[Evaluate[Log[x^#] & /@ Range[3]], {x, 0, 1}, AxesLabel -> {"x", StringForm["ln(``)", Subscript[y, n]]}, PlotLegends -> Placed[StringForm["n = ``", #] & /@ Range[3], {.7, .4}]]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are two solutions.

```
GraphicsRow @
 Table[
   Plot[Log[x^n], {x, 0, 1}, 
     AxesLabel -> {"x", Row[{"ln(", Subscript[y, n], ")"}]}],
   {n, 3}]
```

and

```
GraphicsRow @
  Table[
    Plot[Log[x^n], {x, 0, 1}, AxesLabel -> {"x", ln[Subscript[y, n]]}],
    {n, 3}]
```

Both give

[image: plots]

The solution using `Row` is more generally applicable and is the one I recommend. The other solution works because `ln` is not a defined symbol.

Answer (score 0):

`HoldForm[]` will keep the parentheses from moving around.

```
    Table[Plot[Log[x^n], {x, 0, 1},AxesLabel -> {"x", HoldForm["ln(" Subscript[y, n] ")"]}], {n, 1, 3}]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Table[Plot[Log[x^n], {x, 0, 1}, 
  AxesLabel -> {"x", 
    ToString["Ln"] ~~ ToString["("] ~~ 
     ToString@TraditionalForm[Subscript[y, n]] ~~ ToString[")"]}], {n,
   1, 3}]
```

[image: graphics row with correct display]